# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. API 16

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat

I encountered the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity), but I checked my code and xml files, I use only AppCompat. I am trying to run on api 16. Here where I use it:

[image]

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/main_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:name=".GoogleImageSearcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

styles.xml

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>

</style>
```

styles-v21.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
   <!-- <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

</style>
```

Log

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
        at com.dandewine.user.tocleveroad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
```

Where I missed, any advice?

Comment: Are you using any toolbar in your Activity?

Comment: @ProkashSarkar, yes I using cutom toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , replace

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

by

```
 android:theme="@style/Base.AppTheme" >
```

Comment: It helped, but I wonder why need direct heir AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Manifest file if you have added any incompatible theme to your app (if 'MainActivity' is a child of `AppCompatActivity`.  its theme should be inherited form the Theme.AppCompat or from one of its
    children.

Answer (score -3):

Try setting the min api to 16 or use some additional libraries like [android arsena](https://android-arsenal.com/)